# How to cleanly remove a section of countertop

Tags: kitchens, kitchen-counters

The counter in this kitchen has a section that is narrower than the main section due to having a door next to it.

Although the previous solution has impeccable taste, its just not my style. (see picture).

Is it possible to find purchase a counter top with custom specifications?

Additionally, is it possible to do a clean and professional looking job of cutting into the counter top one might find in a big box store and sealing the open edges created by cutting into it?

The "cut-out" meaning the section of the countertop that must be removed from the uniform countertops sold in big box stores to match the different width on one section of the countertop.

[image]

Comment: @isherwood Someone modified the question and changed the meaning. Reverting it now.

Comment: @isherwood After rereading your edits I think you were closer to the meaning than I originally thought. I edited the question again to make it more specific. Thank you.

Comment: I believe the answer to this is just "hire a counter top company". They have tools to measure exactly what you need to install and custom cut the piece. If you're going to a big box store, sit down with the kitchen designer.

Answer (score 2):

Usually tops like that are built by fitting a base sheet (usually particle board for flatness and smoothness) and edging it with hardwood using miter joints. Then laminate is applied across the entire surface with contact cement. The laminate is then trimmed flush with a router, and a bevel or more detailed edge is routed into the hardwood and laminate simultaneously.

Stain (optional) and several coats of high-quality sealer finish the job. With this technique, virtually any shape is achievable with basic carpentry skills.